# OSError, [Errno 13] Permission denied, thrown when I try to upload load file in django with apache/mod_wsgi server

Tags: python, django, apache, file-upload, wsgi

Here is the trace back

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://mysite.com/admin/content/author/add/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('grappelli',
 'filebrowser',
 'south',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'tinymce',
 'mailchimp',
 'content',
 'categorization',
 'mptt')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  955.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  709.         obj.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1576.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  909.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  872.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  249.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  45.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  168.                 os.makedirs(directory)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  157.     mkdir(name, mode)

Exception Type: OSError at /admin/content/author/add/
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '//media/uploads'
```

Here is my model

```
class ArticleImage(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Title'),
    help_text = _(u'The title for this article image'),
    max_length = 255,
)
alt_text = models.CharField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Alt. Text'),
    help_text = _(u'The alt text for this article image'),
    max_length = 255,
)
image = models.ImageField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Image'),
    upload_to = 'uploads/articleimages/'
)
article = models.ForeignKey(
    Article,
    verbose_name = _(u'Article'),
    help_text = _(u'The article to which this image belongs'),
)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _(u'Image')
    verbose_name_plural = _(u'Images')

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s'%self.title
```

Here are related settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.getcwd() + '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
DEBUG = False
```

Here is my httpd.conf for the media directory

```
Alias /media/ /home/quinton/Sites/prod/media/

<Directory /home/quinton/Sites/prod/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is not a problem when I run everything locally. Only when I push to my server and restart Apache does this occur. I have tried changing the file permission to 777 for the media directory, but still no luck.

Comment: You're sure `os.getcwd()` is giving you what you expect, and not a parent directory? Also, show the lines in httpd.conf that set up the WSGI daemon.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot. I have been pouring my soul into this code for 1 and a half hours. Thanks a million!

Comment: @QuintonRobbins was that the answer? If so, I think you should have MikeDeSimone post that comment as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1):

`os.getcwd()` might not give you what you want. There's no guarantee that the working directory is, say, the one your settings.py file is in.

If you want to work from your settings file's location, then you can use `os.path` and `__file__` in your `settings.py` file:

```
import os.path
# Get the directory the settings.py file is located in.
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

As a bonus, other modules in your project can use this as well:

```
from django.conf import settings
print "Base directory:", settings.BASE_DIR
```